# Bypassing the door sensor of a dish washer

Tags: repair, doors, dishwasher

My dishwasher refuses to start.
At first this was intermittent, now it is a permanent fault.

The dishwasher thinks the door is open, but it is not.

Machine in question: **DCS DD24DUT7 88645-A**

I'm almost certain that the sensor is (infrared?) light based.
I have removed the drawer, and have spotted in the chassis, what I think is, some sort of prism.

I also took the front off the door, and spotted the active side, what I think is a guide for the light source that is housed in a sealed module.

Together, they seem to form some sort of U-shaped light path that can be opened and closed.

I would like to know if there is a DIY fix that lets me bypass this sensor completely? I just want the machine to start washing, and care less about sensing a door that may be open.

On the chassis:

[image: this looks like a plastic prism]

On the door:

[image: this looks like a light source and a light sensor]

Comment: Have you tried to jumper across the switch.  I would start there.

Comment: try placing a strip of light-color masking tape over the whole thing. if that doesn't work, you can short the leads of the sensors; the trick is not shorting the IR LEDs but the phototransistor leads instead. a multimeter should report a voltage on the LED leads, and nothing for the sensor leads.

Comment: Thanks dandavis, I will definitely try that, once I undo my subsequent screw up. While dismantling the "badge isolator" in the door, I broke the Ferrite Core, and now nothing works anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix mine by bypassing the led door sensor switch entirely. Worked like a charm. Desolder the led emitter and receiver. One contact each side of each, get tweezers and it does not take much heat. My emitter was already loose (hence the problem) and it melted real quick when I tried to reattach it, meaning I was looking at a whole new board or something else. I'm glad I tried something else.

Solder thin wires to the two terminals for one (the LED emitter or LED receiver), and run as jumpers between them (each jumper wire from emitter to receiver, upper wire to upper wire, lower to lower). Now the dishwasher always thinks it's closed. The door still locks but now in any door position. Yes, you will be able to pull open the dw door while it is running, and keeps running, after this mod. It is not a big deal, just lock it first. Also it is still not exactly easy to open (pressure differences and good seals?) anyway, the fix removes none of the usefulness.